# Creating stack using linked list

Tags: c, arrays, list, stack

I'm trying to create my stack, using my linked listed functions that I already created. I have the following:

```
listNode *createList()
{
    listNode *anyNode;
    anyNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    anyNode->next = NULL;
    return anyNode;
}

stack *createStack()
{
    stack *temp;
    stack.list = createList();
    return temp;
}
```

and in my main I call it using:

```
int main(void)
{   
    stack *theStack;
    theStack = createStack();
    return(0);
}
```

I defined my stack as:

```
typedef struct stack {
    listNode *list;
}stack;
```

I get a compiler error: expected identifier or '(' at my stack.list = createList() call in my createStack function. I'm not sure why.

My main works if I change

```
stack *theStack
```

into

```
 listNode *list
```

then just call it as: list = createList();

Comment: `return(0)` looks as if `return` was a function, it's not.

Comment: @iharob and what's your point??? it's perfectly valid, take a look at the BSD source if you aren't happy about it.

Comment: @self there is no point, just style advice.

Comment: Do you have any questions about the actual implementation (the interesting part)?

Comment: @iharob go tell that to the freebsd guys

Comment: @self The BSD source code is not the [tag:c] standard. The fact that it's valid doesn't mean it's not ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: @self: It might shadow typos. That style is deprecated nowadays, but was popular in the 70ies/80ies. Projects don't tend to change their coding style if not required, but still it is not advisable for new programs.

Comment: i'm intimately aware of that, but you're acting as if's abnormal to use parens in an expression; also since when does the C standard dictate style?

Comment: @self I am not acting like that, I am just trying to point out that it's deprecated style that and that it's not needed. Read my comment again please.

Comment: @self: I can't read that from the original comment. It does not state it was an error. And you hardly would write `int i; i = (3);`, would you?

Comment: no, but if i wanted to log a message every time we return from a function I could do `#define return(exp) ....`

Comment: @self, I don't see why someone would do that at all. Code should be readable in many ways. One of which, is that it should do only what you can read that it does. Obscure things like a macro redefining `return` are and it's simply my opinion, bad. Please do not answer this comment because this is not what comments are for. And also, because this is like having a discussion about RELIGION, so we are both right and wrong at the same time.

Comment: Why not try passing in an int as an argument when creating a list? This way you can make a linked list of a given size. You just have to modify the createList function a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declared `temp` as a pointer of type `stack` but then you write

```
stack.list = ...
```

`stack` in your code is a type not a variable, you can't use it like that.

You need a variable instead, something like

```
stack my_stack;
my_stack.list = ...
```

if you want it to be a pointer, then you need to use `malloc()` to allocate space for it.

Comment: I think that worked. I have a question for printing now. I wrote my push function and I think it works as well, how do I test printing the nodes in my stack go? Im not sure how it works since my stack only takes a listNode* list.

Comment: In my linked list, I would just print printf("%d",list->value);

Comment: @iharob when you return a pointer to this `my_stack` variable, it will be returning a local variable. Better to declare a pointer and call the `createstack` function on it.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I never suggested to do that. If the `stack` variable will only be used locally there is no harm in doing it without a pointer, although mostly that would not be the case. My answer tries to illustrate the syntax error rather than how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `createstack` function.

```
stack.list = createList()
```

`stack` is a global variable, and you should be using the local variable `temp` here. You need to allocate size for the stack structure also here.

```
stack *createStack()
{
  stack *temp;
  temp = malloc(sizeof(stack));
  temp->list = createList();
  return temp;
}
```